# Firebase Functions: route every URL through function and serve from "hosting"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to get every url in a subdomain to be routed through a firebase function. This is my configuration:

The functions file:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.handleWebRequest = functions
  .region('europe-west1')
  .https
  .onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.send('Currently down.');
  });
```

My `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "handleWebRequest"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "source": "firebase-functions",
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ]
  }
}
```

When I deploy the hosting and functions, and go to the URL in my browser, I expect to see "Currently down" for every route I open. However, every route **except** the root route shows the "Currently down" message, and the root route shows the `index.html` that I deployed.

So, in a nutshell:

`/` shows my `index.html` (which I don't want)
`/whatever` shows "Currently down." (which **is** what I want)

The reason I'm trying to route everything through the function, is because I want to shield the website with HTTP Basic Auth, which is "not natively supported" by Firebase.

Answer (score 3):

This is most probably because you still have the `index.html` file under the `public` folder.

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#use_a_web_framework):

> Note: The static files in the public directory take precedence over
>   the rewrites, so any static files will be served alongside the Cloud
>   Functions endpoints.

If you remove the `index.html` file it should work the way you expect.

Comment: Thank you, will accept your answer or the other one depending on what we decide to use.

Answer (score 3):

Your function is deployed to the "europe-west1" region, but Firebase Hosting currently only supports the default "us-central1".  This is stated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions):

> Important: Firebase Hosting supports Cloud Functions in us-central1 only.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to just host the function in `europe-west1`, including the website's HTML + assets? Would this be more expensive / less performant?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're proposing.  Perhaps you could give it a try, and post another question if you get stuck with that?